# Insert SQL Server Coluna nao recebe valor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Estou tentando da insert em uma tabela simples, porém um campo dela, não esta salvando o valor que estou passando pra ela, e o mais estranho é que todas as outras colunas recebem direitinho. 
Exemplo

```
INSERT TabelaExemplo (id, nome, outroId) values (1,'Gabriela', 2)
```

É inserido com sucesso, porem a coluna `outroID` aparece null quando dou o select nessa tabela. importante levar em consideração que a coluna outroId é do tipo `INT` e aceita valores `null`. Porém ao passar valores deveria persistir os dados certo?

Outros dados da coluna dados pelo `sp_help`

```
Column_name outroId
Type int    
Computed no
Length  4
Prec 10
Scale 0
Nullable yes
TrimTrailingBlanks  (n/a)
FixedLenNullInSource (n/a)  
Collation NULL
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia do por que isso esta acontecendo?

Comment: Como está executando o código? Isto é, em qual ambiente. // A coluna id é chave primária ou coluna do tipo unique? // Experimente repetir o comando, mas fornecendo um valor de id que tenha certeza que não conste da tabela.

Comment: esse outroID na pratica é para referencia de certa forma um historico de um ID que foi alterado, por isso ele tem que existir na tabela. 
a primeira coluna ID, é uma primart Key e foreign key em outra tabela. 

Estou fazendo isso em um ambiente de testes.

Comment: Existem triggers nesta tabela ?